# Impossible to mock one class with mockito: Receive NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have around 100 unit test in my Android project. Everything work perfectly. I use JUnit + Mockito + PowerMock (when dealing with difficult static class).

While writing my latest test, I was surprise with this very strange error that I don't understand.

When I do this in the setUp() function:

```
playerAccessor = mock(PlayerAccessor.class);
```

All the tests crash with this very strange error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/media/MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:349)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:422)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:457)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:124)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:60)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:52)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1258)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1135)
    at com.stingray360.clap.ondemand.OnDemandMessageHandlerTest.setUp(OnDemandMessageHandlerTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 62 more
```

My only clue is that the `PlayerAccessor` have a function called register which take an object Player which implement the `OnCompletionListener` interface. But I'm not mocking the `Player`, I'm mocking the `PlayerAccessor`.

Do I need to specify something in my mock function so it doesn't try to mock every object used by the PlayerAccessor? Is it something missing from my test (import???).

***EDIT***

One answer suggest me to put the needed library (com.google.android) in the "test" scope but since it's the android library, the scope NEED to be "provided". If I change it, it's true that my unit test start to work but when I run the app, I receive big errors in the console telling me that it's a very bad thing to do to include the android jar... So what are the other solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class you're mocking imports another class you have to have that class on the classpath or the class loader will fail, regardless whether you're actually using any of the functionality afforded by it.

If you're using maven for builds you can easily add a dependency jar with test scope

Comment: Ok, I know the needed library is "com.google.android" but unfortunately, the scope is already set to "provided" since it's provided by the client at runtime. When I put it to "test", the unit test start to work but I can't compile my application anymore because the compilator complains in the console that it's a VERY VERY bad thing to do to ship the android library with the app... What can I do?

Comment: I was hoping somebody with first hand knowledge of android dev would chime in, but since it's been quiet, I suppose the android plugin complains because it sees the classes during its phase, so I would try leaving the dependency as provided, but also add the dependency to the surefire plugin

Comment: I don't use surefire plugin... Should I?

Comment: It's the default plugin running the tests, there's a default configuration inferred if you do not specify it in the pom. There's nothing preventing you from specifying it manually though

Comment: I think we use maven almost only for the pom.xml file which help us manage the dependencies. It's also used on the build server.I have tried to put the surefire pluging and testNG and I have never found any output on my computer (reports) when I run the test using eclipse JUnit run configuration... Do I need to launch unit test using a "Maven Build"?

Comment: Assuming eclipse is aware of maven nature of a project it should respect maven configuration. You don't need to configure the plugin any different, just add the dependency in <plugin><dependencies>. Also, this is all my suggestion, I don't know if it would work

Comment: I finally got the test working with using a Maven Test run configuration instead of a JUnit Test run configuration in eclipse. I did not add anything to the dependencies, Maven know how to work with that. It's ok for now but one day I will need to create another question for them both to work. Thanks for you help man.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse should respect pom configuration